# 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'etudiant'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After modifying my database context, everything bugged and i'm not able to repair it...

So i've added the 3 following connections (i know they are referring to the same table, they have just been created for testing and try to find one how is able to work...) :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=ManyToManyTest;integrated security=True;context connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ManyToMany" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=ManyToManyTest;integrated security=True;context connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v13.0;Initial Catalog=ManyToManyTest;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

(I've no real knowledge about all the parameters of the connectionString, if someone has some kind of help for this, i'm interested :) )

In my IdentityModel.cs i can see :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("SchoolContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

I've try replacing the SchoolContext by all 3 above without success...
My errors are on one of my controller :

```
    public class etudiantsController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: etudiants
    public ActionResult Index(String sortOrder, string searchString)
    {
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        var students = from s in db.etudiant
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            students = students.Where(s => s.prenom.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.nom.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.mail.Contains(searchString));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.prenom);
                break;
            default:
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.prenom);
                break;
        }
        return View(students.ToList());
```

The error are on the line var students = from s in db.etudiant (means student in english) and is situated on the db.etudiant

The complete error message is the following :

> Error CS1061  'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for
>   'etudiant' and no extension method 'etudiant' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   ManyToManyApp   \Projects\ManyToManyApp\ManyToManyApp\Controllers\etudiantsController.cs

Comment: The error says there is no `etudiant` property on `ApplicationDbContext`. It doesn't relate to the database itself, it refers only to that class.

Comment: Do you have a property called `etudiant` in your ApplicationDbContext class ?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to create models or expose existing models via the db context class.

Comment: If this is a code first project then you need to create a database migration to update your database to the state of your newly edited model, also this will reveal the changes for comparison purposes to your database.  `add-migration` in the package manager console window.

Comment: Please post the complete ApplicationDbContext . It's the one from the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add property for entity set:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("SchoolContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)

    public DbSet<Student> etudiant { get; set;} // add this
}
```

where Student is your entity class

Comment: And then:  etudiant -> Etudiants , capitalization is almost as important as pluralization.